# MySql ConnectionString without Database name to create a database in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, database-connection

I have got a situation where i do need to create a database into MYSQL by using the connection string needed to get into mysql server.Till Now i have used connectionstring with database names .So in this situation what will be the connectionstring structure to execute my create database queries into mysql server.

I need the Connectionstring for localhost ..

Please help me ..

Comment: @SonerGönül How can i open connection with mysql server without specifying database name in Connectionstring

Comment: mysql provides some default databases like mysql, information_schema.. try with any on of the db name

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can optionally omit the `database` parameter in connection string. Doing so, you get a connection to the database server but you are not connected to any specific database.

**Part of [Example from MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connections-string.html)**:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn;
string myConnectionString;

//myConnectionString = "server=localhost;uid=root;pwd=12345;database=test;";
myConnectionString = "server=localhost;uid=root;pwd=12345;";

try
{
    conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
    conn.Open();
}
catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

But you have to use database name to qualify the table or other object names within your queries.

**Example**:

```
select * from so.tbl_so_q23676633;
```

In the above example, `'so'` is the database qualifier for table `'tbl_so_q23676633'`.

Answer (score 1):

Using OleDb you can achieve this.
   // OleDb

```
    using System.Data.OleDb;
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(); 
    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=MySqlProv; Data Source=ServerName; User id=UserName; Password=Secret";
    conn.Open();
```

For more info [MySQL Connection string without database](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/601858/Howplustoplusgetplusmysqlplusconnectionpluswithout)
Another Useful link [Types of MySQL connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/)