# Connecting to remote database through mysql client

Tags: mysql, database, database-connection, mysql-workbench

I have the connection parameters for connecting to a remote database - host name, database name, username and password. Which ever mysql client I try to connect with, has only three parameter fields for connecting - host, username and password. Where and how do I enter the database name for my connection?

Comment: Refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23677221/1548894)

Comment: This is connecting through application code, but I need to connect through a client app, like Mysql Workbench, which has no database parameter field when creating a connection.

Comment: I don't know about your client software, but if no database name is asked, then it may connect to the server and it will let you access all databases according to your credential permissions. So you will be able to choose your database once authenticated. [Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-getting-started-tutorial-create-connection.html) is a tutorial I found searching a bit, maybe it's useful for you.

Comment: The problem is, I have always accessed mysql databases through phpmyadmin until now. This time I have these four parameters, but when I try to connect with host name, user name and password, without database name, the connection can't be established. On the other hand, the website which uses this database has these exact same parameters, and it works perfectly, so I am sure that the parameters are ok...